# How do I turn on syntax highlighting for StringTemplate templates (*.st) in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, stringtemplate

I have a string template file (.st) in IntelliJ that I would like to see syntax highlighting on. How can I turn this on? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Don't know what String templates are exactly, but if you want JS highlighting for files with custom extension, you can go to Settings/Editor/File types and add `*.st` under _Registred Patterns_.

Comment: JavaScript highlighting can be quite ok in Intellij Idea, however, real support of JavaScript comes with Ultimate Edition. Did you consider that?

Comment: I ended up just using the HTML syntax for my .st files and it's close enough for me. I just wondered if there was anything already out there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is - you can't.

Someone must first implement a syntax highlighter plugin for the format.
The StringTemplate author, Terrence Parr, has begun work on such a plugin for String Template 4 but it does not support the older .st file format.
I tried the plugin. Even on .stg files it is not ideal if you use a dark editor theme.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use HTML syntax for `*.st` files. You can set this in Preference > File types > HTML.